# Is there an API somewhere that allow to compare one postal code with a list of postal code to find which one is nearest?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-services

We need your help. I have a problem that i need to solve and i haven't found any concrete solutions to this. In ASP.NET MVC we want to implement a specific feature.

This is for a student training course application, we know that a student will do a training course outside and inside a specific town. The student will give out two or three postal code which are friends, familly etc.

**What i need to do is to compare one postal code with a list of postal code to find which one is nearest.**

The list of postal code are the emplacement where the student will do the training course.

For this task, its obvious that i need an API or some WebService. Its also obvious that this task will require high trafic if we cannot pass a list of postal code rather than one postal code.

We know that google might have something to do that but it only accept one postal code which isnt what we are looking for.

So is there an API somewhere, a way or whatever that allow to compare one postal code with a list of postal code to find which one is nearest ? Any ideas ?

Thanks.

Edit #1: Please note that im looking for a way to pass a **list of postal** code to one postal code. The list may be very big and may need to compare with another list.

Comment: Maybe this can help http://www.freemaptools.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://briancray.com/2009/04/01/how-to-calculate-the-distance-between-two-addresses-with-javascript-and-google-maps-api/

Comment: Is there a limit to Google Maps API requests for this?

Comment: Is there a way to pass a list ? What happen when you have to pass 500 postal code for 500 others postal code.. that 250000 requests. It is going to be slow ? That why i said i know google could do it. But can the api return a list ? this is probably the main major problem in my question.

Comment: @Rushino:  If you need that kind of functionality you should consider purchasing some GIS software.  If you need to run that many comparisons at once a services-based API would probably be too slow.

Answer (score 0):

We are currently using the Microsoft MapPoint 2010 API to find the distance and it is working in early testing (for Great Britain)

There still doesn't seem to be any web services that support high volumes of lookups well

Comment: I should have also mentioned, for our requirements "as the crow flies" is not enough, this has to take into account driving distances.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution would be to buy the Cameo data - this has every postcode in the UK with a grid reference, you can just use a bit of pythagoras to calculate the distances between postcodes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking at batch processing postal codes as a requirement for your application, the suggested path will be to either purchase a commercial product which will be a combination of a library and a database. You would have to ensure that the product is meant for batch processing applications though i.e. if you are looking to scale up this would be critical. Otherwise you can invest in a home grown solution by calculating the distances using the latitudes and the longitudes (example):

www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Hope you resolve your issue soon, good luck.

Update: Check out http://www.geonames.org/